# Callback in Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

i have a problem with my Alexa Skill. The code is like this:

```
 var options = { method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://98f8cd20.ngrok.io/products',
      headers: 
       { 'Postman-Token': 'f4e1b171-aae5-46d5-baeb-7903978cf10c',
         'cache-control': 'no-cache',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };


    const callExternalApi = (callback) => {
     request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
          return callback(error)
      }
            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            return callback(data)

    })
    } module.exports.callApi = callExternalApi
```

and

```
apicaller.callApi(function(antwort){
     var test = antwort;

    console.log(test)
})
```

When i test it in my sublime editor there is no problem at all but when i test it with my alexa Skill i get an error. The code over there looks like this:

```
 'AllCarsIntent': function () {

        apicaller.callApi(function(antwort){
         var test = antwort.count;

          this.response.speak(test).listen("Tell me what you think is the world's most popular sport.")
          this.emit(':responseReady')


         //.listen("Tell me what you think is the world's most popular sport.")
         //this.emit(':responseReady')
     });
```

I think there is a problem with "this" in my callback. This is how my error looks like:

> START RequestId: 4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7 Version: $LATEST
>   2018-11-06T10:53:53.718Z  4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7    Warning:
>   Application ID is not set
>   2018-11-06T10:53:54.118Z  4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7    TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
>       at /var/task/index.js:29:12
>       at Request.request [as _callback] (/var/task/data.js:19:12)
>       at Request.self.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30) END RequestId: 4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7 REPORT RequestId:
>   4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7  Duration: 440.67 ms Billed
>   Duration: 500 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
>   RequestId: 4064b501-e1b2-11e8-b227-bb50cdd263c7 Process exited before
>   completing request

Anyone has an idea what my mistake is? I would really appreciate your help!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The context is lost once inside the API call function. *this* does not refer anymore to the outer context. Define the variable *test* outside the *callApi* function then assign the value inside the *calllApi* function, and then do the *speak* and *emit* also outside the *callApi* function. You'll have to wait for the data of the API call to come back so you need to use *async*/*await* and node v8+
[Here's](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/ba0c8e5af0491a6cb88c39bd7cd5c0c7#file-index-js-L13) an example of such API call but using the latest version of the ASK SDK (please migrate to this one, the one you're using is deprecated).